# Can't connect to local postgresql server from my docker container

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to connect to local postgresql server from my docker container.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: '3'

services:
    ...
    backend:
        build:
            context: '.'
            dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
        ports:
            - '8000:80'
            - '8001:8001'
        env_file:
            - .env-docker
        image: backend-django:latest
    ...
```

This is my `.env-docker`.

```
DEBUG=True
SECRET_KEY=******
DATABASE_USER=postgres
DATABASE_NAME=postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
DATABASE_HOST=host.docker.internal
DATABASE_PORT=5432
```

This is my `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM python:3.11
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

...

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "config.wsgi"]
```

It was working in Windows but not in Ubuntu now.

Is it related to postgresql?
I'm using the same version of postgresql and I can connect to local postgresl using PgAdmin.

How can I connect to postgresql server from my docker container?

(I added this to my docker container in `docker-compose.yml` (from this post - [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)) but still not working.

```
extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: Honestly, I would recommend to also containerize the postgres database.

Comment: I added "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" to my docker-compose.yml but still can't connect.

Comment: where is running your postgres DB, and what client you are using to connect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your container in `docker-compose.yml`.

```
extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

If you keep getting errors, change listen_addresses in `postgresql.conf`

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

And add these lines to your `pg_hba.conf`

```
host    all all 0.0.0.0/0   scram-sha-256
host    all all ::/0    scram-sha-256
```

After this, restart the postgresql service.

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```